# How to create/ update task to run in future using Timer in microservice system

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, timertask

[Problem]
I have service that have multiple instance and run in microservice system.
In service, I use Timer instance to run task in future

```
public class CustomizedTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private String message;
    private String sender;
    private String reciver;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // todo somthing
    }

}

@Service
public MyTimerService {


    public void initAfterStartOn() {
        // get all task that have due date greater than now
        // for_each and call newTask() function
    }

    public void newTask() {
        
        Date startedAt = new Date(new Date().getTime() + ((long)5 * 60 * 60);
        
        CustomizedTimerTask timerTask = new CustomizedTimerTask();
        timerTask.setSender("sender");
        timerTask.setRevicer("receiver");
        timerTask.setMessage("Hi, nice to meet you");
        timer.schedule(new CustomizedTimerTask(), new Date(startedAt));
        
        // save CustomizedTimerTask to Database
    }
}
```

Everything will be ok if I run only one instance. But if I have multiple instance and one of all is down and run later. It will run `initAfterStartOn()` it cause task will be duplicate.
Can someone give me advice on this?

Currently, I have not found any solution yet.

Comment: Get all tasks from where? A queue? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. Tasks are saved in the database

2. After running the service, I will call the initAfterStartOn() function to get the task information in the database and start the task again (this going to cause a duplicated task problem if I run multiple  instance of service)

I expect that each task runs only once in multiple service instances

Answer (score 0):

You can try using @Scheduled annotation

```
@Scheduled (cron = "0 0/10 * * * *", zone = "IST")
@SchedulerLock(name="createPromotionJob",lockAtLeastFor = "PTSM",lockAtMostFor="PTOM") 
public void scheduledCreatePromotion() {
```